Pine Script Loop
I'm trying to do a loop on sales by retrieving IDs that I put in variables
I have x Long, and I want to sell 100%
I don't know if it's possible
idAchatNotSellBis = 0

for idAchatNotSell = idFirstAchatNotSell to idLastAchatNotSell

    if(ichi4h == 1 and close < leadLine1[25])
        idAchatNotSellBis += idAchatNotSell
        strategy.exit("Trade_" + str.tostring(idAchatNotSell), qty_percent = 100, profit = 1)

My first Trade is Trade_1
My second Trade_2
...
my loop always returns Trade_1
When I buy, it's ok, the name is good, Trade_1, Trade_2, Trade_3... You can look the picture

But When I Sell 100%, the name is not good, I have always Trade_1, the loop is not ok. You can look the picture

I try this changement, but it's not good
idAchatNotSellBis = 1
for idAchatNotSell = 1 to 4
    if(ichi4h == 1 and close < leadLine1[25])
        //idAchatNotSellBis := idAchatNotSell
        strategy.exit("Trade_" + str.tostring(idAchatNotSellBis), qty_percent = 100, profit = 1)
        idAchatNotSellBis := idAchatNotSell + 1

Thank you for your help and sorry for my english

Nobody can help me ?
